# laravel 5 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages.sender_id' in 'having clause'

Tags: sql, laravel-5, sqlexception

I am migrating my site from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5.0, and have been doing so for the past 4 days. After going through so many errors, the latest error I am facing is its throwing this exception:

`PDOException in Connection.php line 292: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages.sender_id' in 'having clause'`.

It was working find before migrating the site and I didn't change the database.

I have a `JobsController` named controller which is producing the error. Here is the function :

```
    public function index() 
  {
    $categories = Client::find(Auth::user()->id)->categories;
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $category_arr[] = $category->id;
    }

    $jobs = Job::leftJoin('messages', function($join)
                                     {
                                       $join->on('jobs.id', '=', 'messages.job_id')
                                             ->where('messages.sender_id', '=', getLoggedInId());
                                     })
               ->whereIn('category_id', $category_arr)
               ->where('status', 1)
               ->where('request_for', 0)
               ->groupBy('jobs.id')
               ->havingRaw('messages.sender_id <> '.getLoggedInId().' or messages.sender_id is null')
               ->select(['jobs.*', 'messages.job_id', 'messages.sender_id'])
               ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
               ->paginate(10);

    $title = "Available Requests";

    $this->layout = View::make('layouts.loggedin', compact('title'));
    $this->layout->content = View::make('jobs/index', compact('jobs'));
  }
```

Please help to solve this. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Here is the message table :

```
    id  int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
message     text    NO      NULL    
sender_id   int(11)     NO      NULL    
receiver_id     int(11)     NO      NULL    
job_id  int(11)     NO      NULL    
created_at  datetime    NO      NULL    
updated_at  datetime    NO      NULL
```

Comment: You are grouping by `jobs.id`, so `message.sender_id` is not in the `having` clause, because it is not in the result set of the `group by`.  I don't know why it ever worked, perhaps because the underlying database was MySQL that allows such bogosity (although you can turn it off with the right parameter settings).

Comment: I guess you are right. I removed the having clause and it works now. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.